# Streamlit image processing

Tags: image-processing, video-streaming, opencv, streamlit, python

I have created a Python app that gets a webcam frame and then processes it with a ML classifier model, and detects Sign Language words, then sends the processed frame back. Since I'm new deploying and accessing user media devices, I used streamlit to make it easier. The problem is, that my predicts annotations are not reaching my localhost in streamlit, let me show you:

This is how it should work, the app is running with Flask on a Flask local deployment:
[image: App working with Flask in local]

And this is how the app looks like, deployed on streamlit:
[image: App not working on Streamlit]

I had to hardcode a string into cv2.putText() function in order to test that cv2 worked well:

[image]

So putText and the other cv2 functions are working, but I cant/dont know how to use logging in streamlit to see where the mistake is... I guess it has something to do with the ML frame processing part. Here it is the streamlit app.py code.

```
from streamlit_webrtc import VideoProcessorBase, RTCConfiguration,WebRtcMode,webrtc_streamer
from utils import *
import cv2
import streamlit as st
import mediapipe as mp
import av

RTC_CONFIGURATION = RTCConfiguration(
    {"iceServers": [{"urls": ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]}]}
)

def main():
    st.header("Live stream processing")

    sign_language_det = "Sign Language Live Detector"
    app_mode = st.sidebar.selectbox( "Choose the app mode",
        [
            sign_language_det
        ],
    )

    st.subheader(app_mode)

    if app_mode == sign_language_det:
        sign_language_detector()
 

def sign_language_detector():

    class OpenCVVideoProcessor(VideoProcessorBase):
        def recv(self, frame: av.VideoFrame) -> av.VideoFrame:
            img = frame.to_ndarray(format="bgr24")

            mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic # Holistic model
            mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils # Drawing utilities
            
            # Actions that we try to detect
            actions = np.array(['hello', 'thanks', 'iloveyou'])

            # Load the model from Modelo folder:

            model = load_model('model.h5',actions)

            # 1. New detection variables
            sequence = []
            sentence = []
            threshold = 0.8

            # Set mediapipe model 
            with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
                while True:
                    #img = frame.to_ndarray(format="bgr24")
                    flip_img = cv2.flip(img,1)

                    # Make detections
                    image, results = mediapipe_detection(flip_img, holistic)
                    
                    # Draw landmarks
                    draw_styled_landmarks(image, results)
                    
                    # 2. Prediction logic
                    keypoints = extract_keypoints(results)
                    sequence.append(keypoints)
                    sequence = sequence[-30:]
                    
                    if len(sequence) == 30:
                        res = model.predict(np.expand_dims(sequence, axis=0))[0]
                        #print(actions[np.argmax(res)])

                    #3. Viz logic
                        if res[np.argmax(res)] > threshold: 
                            if len(sentence) > 0: 
                                if actions[np.argmax(res)] != sentence[-1]:
                                    sentence.append(actions[np.argmax(res)])
                            else:
                                sentence.append(actions[np.argmax(res)])

                        if len(sentence) > 5: 
                            sentence = sentence[-5:]

                        # Viz probabilities
                        image = prob_viz(res, actions, image)

                    cv2.rectangle(image, (0,0), (640, 40), (234, 234, 77), 1)
                    cv2.putText(image, ' '.join(sentence), (3,30), 
                                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    return av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(image,format="bgr24")

    webrtc_ctx = webrtc_streamer(
        key="opencv-filter",
        mode=WebRtcMode.SENDRECV,
        rtc_configuration=RTC_CONFIGURATION,
        video_processor_factory=OpenCVVideoProcessor,
        async_processing=True,
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And here the working app.py with Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response

from imutils.video import VideoStream

from utils import *

import mediapipe as mp

import threading

import argparse

import time

import cv2

# initialize the output frame and a lock used to ensure thread-safe

# exchanges of the output frames (useful when multiple browsers/tabs

# are viewing the stream)

outputFrame = None

lock = threading.Lock()

app = Flask(__name__)

mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic # Holistic model

mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils # Drawing utilities

# initialize the video stream and allow the camera sensor to

# warmup

#vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=1).start()

vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()

time.sleep(2.0)

@app.route('/')

def index():

    return render_template('index.html')

def classify():

        global vs, outputFrame, lock

        mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic # Holistic model

        mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils # Drawing utilities 

        # Actions that we try to detect

        actions = np.array(['hello', 'thanks', 'iloveyou'])

        # Load the model from Modelo folder:

        model = load_model('model.h5',actions)

        # 1. New detection variables

        sequence = []

        sentence = []

        threshold = 0.8

        # Set mediapipe model 

        with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:

            while True:

                frame = vs.read()

                flip_img = cv2.flip(frame,1)

                # Make detections

                image, results = mediapipe_detection(flip_img, holistic)

                

                # Draw landmarks

                draw_styled_landmarks(image, results)

                

                # 2. Prediction logic

                keypoints = extract_keypoints(results)

                sequence.append(keypoints)

                sequence = sequence[-30:]

                

                if len(sequence) == 30:

                    res = model.predict(np.expand_dims(sequence, axis=0))[0]

                    #print(actions[np.argmax(res)])

                #3. Viz logic

                    if res[np.argmax(res)] > threshold: 

                        if len(sentence) > 0: 

                            if actions[np.argmax(res)] != sentence[-1]:

                                sentence.append(actions[np.argmax(res)])

                        else:

                            sentence.append(actions[np.argmax(res)])

                    if len(sentence) > 5: 

                        sentence = sentence[-5:]

                    # Viz probabilities

                    image = prob_viz(res, actions, image)

                cv2.rectangle(image, (0,0), (640, 40), (245, 117, 16), -1)

                cv2.putText(image, ' '.join(sentence), (3,30), 

                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

                #cv2.imshow('LIVE SIGN DETECTION', image)

                with lock:

                    outputFrame = image.copy()

                    

def generate():

    # grab global references to the output frame and lock variables

    global outputFrame, lock

    # loop over frames from the output stream

    while True:

        # wait until the lock is acquired

        with lock:

            # check if the output frame is available, otherwise skip

            # the iteration of the loop

            if outputFrame is None:

                continue

            # encode the frame in JPEG format

            (flag, encodedImage) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", outputFrame)

            # ensure the frame was successfully encoded

            if not flag:

                continue

        # yield the output frame in the byte format

        yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + 

            bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')

@app.route("/video")

def video():

    # return the response generated along with the specific media

    # type (mime type)

    return Response(generate(),

        mimetype = "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # construct the argument parser and parse command line arguments

    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    ap.add_argument("-i", "--ip", type=str, required=True,

        help="ip address of the device")

    ap.add_argument("-o", "--port", type=int, required=True,

        help="ephemeral port number of the server (1024 to 65535)")

    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    # start a thread that will perform motion detection

    t = threading.Thread(target=classify)

    t.daemon = True

    t.start()

    app.run(host=args["ip"],port=args["port"],debug=True,threaded=True,use_reloader=False)

    # release the video stream pointer

    vs.stop()
```

My custom utils module are just some functions to make the predictions and plot the detection landmarks on face and hands, as well as the ML model creation:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import mediapipe as mp
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
import os

mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic # Holistic model
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils # Drawing utilities

def mediapipe_detection(image, model):
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # COLOR CONVERSION BGR 2 RGB
    image.flags.writeable = False                  # Image is no longer writeable
    results = model.process(image)                 # Make prediction
    image.flags.writeable = True                   # Image is now writeable 
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) # COLOR COVERSION RGB 2 BGR
    return image, results

def draw_landmarks(image, results):
    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.face_landmarks, mp_holistic.FACEMESH_CONTOURS) # Draw face connections
    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS) # Draw pose connections
    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.left_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS) # Draw left hand connections
    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.right_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS) # Draw right hand connections
    
def draw_styled_landmarks(image, results):
    # Draw face connections
    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.face_landmarks, mp_holistic.FACEMESH_CONTOURS, 
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,110,10), thickness=1, circle_radius=1), 
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,256,121), thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
                             ) 
    # Draw pose connections
    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,22,10), thickness=2, circle_radius=4), 
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,44,121), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                             ) 
    # Draw left hand connections
    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.left_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS, 
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(121,22,76), thickness=2, circle_radius=4), 
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(121,44,250), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                             ) 
    # Draw right hand connections  
    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.right_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS, 
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=4), 
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                             )

def extract_keypoints(results):
    pose = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z, res.visibility] for res in results.pose_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.pose_landmarks else np.zeros(33*4)
    face = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z] for res in results.face_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.face_landmarks else np.zeros(468*3)
    lh = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z] for res in results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.left_hand_landmarks else np.zeros(21*3)
    rh = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z] for res in results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.right_hand_landmarks else np.zeros(21*3)
    return np.concatenate([pose, face, lh, rh])


def prob_viz(res, actions, input_frame):
    colors = [(245,117,16), (117,245,16), (16,117,245)]
    output_frame = input_frame.copy()
    for num, prob in enumerate(res):
        cv2.rectangle(output_frame, (0,60+num*40), (int(prob*100), 90+num*40), colors[num], -1)
        cv2.putText(output_frame, actions[num], (0, 85+num*40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255,255,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        
    return output_frame

def load_model(model_path,actions):
    model = Sequential()

    # Layers
    model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, activation='relu', input_shape=(30,1662)))
    model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))
    model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions.shape[0], activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
    model.load_weights(model_path)

    return model
```

Sorry for the post length, but wanted to give full details of my app.